# Verify an XPath in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

How can I verify a given xpath string is valid in C#/.NET?

I'm not sure just running the XPath and catching exceptions is a valid solution (putting aside the bile in my throat for a moment) - what if tomorrow I run into some other input I haven't tested against?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How can I verify a given XPath string is valid in C#/.NET?

You try to build an `XPathExpression` from it and catch the exception.

```
try 
{
    XPathExpression.Compile(xPathString);
}
catch (XPathException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("XPath syntax error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Try it on what, specifically? Can't I get to some other code path that will fail (when running this XPath on some other text)

Comment: Darn. I just typed it into the answer instead of trying it with VS first. Of course "XPathDocument" was wrong.

Comment: Simple.. XPathExpression.Compile(xPathString); does the same

Comment: @Prasad You're right, I was thinking too complicated back then. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For a shorter version than [@Tomalak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308953/225292), you can just use the [XPathExpression.Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163317%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method:

```
string xpath = "/some/xpath";

try
{
    XPathExpression expr = XPathExpression.Compile(xpath);
}
catch (XPathException)
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer is very close to what Tomalak wrote (fixed compilation error & put a mandatory body to the XML):

```
public static class XPathValidator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Throws an XPathException if <paramref name="xpath"/> is not a valid XPath
    /// </summary>
    public static void Validate(string xpath)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<xml></xml>")))
        {
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(stream);
            XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
            nav.Compile(xpath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer again, I did not intend to use "XPathDocument" at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 'mild' regular expression to filter out complete garbage. If it passes the regex, just execute the query and catch exceptions, like mentioned above...