# How to get all namespaces of xml document for correct XPath evaluating?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xdoc

I try to evaluate simple xpath

```
"//pr:Name"
```

for this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pr:Products xmlns:pr="http://www.example.com/">
    <pr:Name>Coffee</pr:Name>
</pr:Products>
```

but I get xml file in run-time i.e. I can't fill XmlNamespaceManager using method AddNamespace() (this why evaluating failed). I tried to do this trick

```
    XDocument xdoc;
    XmlReader reader;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    }
    var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
    var xpath = "//pr:Name";
    var xvalue = xdoc.XPathEvaluate(xpath, nsManager);
```

but it does not help me.
Do you have any idea how to resolve namespaces for XPath or evaluate XPath in other way?
Thank you!

Comment: You can possibly find your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920082/xml-reading-child-nodes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903671/how-can-i-access-a-single-xml-elements-value-using-c-net-web-pages-with-webmat

Comment: @Usama, you suggest use XmlDocument instead of XDocument? But how it help me to resolve namespaces?

Comment: **Try this** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796231/how-does-xpath-deal-with-xml-namespaces

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath

Comment: Usama, I should not defeat namespaces. It is not my case

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308926/verify-an-xpath-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know namespace at compile time, you might probably use this XPath:

```
//*[local-name() = 'Name']
```

This XPath selects all `Name` elements.

Comment: This solution defeats element namespace, but it is suitable for the first time. Thanks!